# Which one is true: try to not repeat it or try not to repeat it?

Tags: phrase-meaning, phrase-usage, infinitive-constructions

Which one is true: try to not repeat it or try not to repeat it?

English is my favorite lesson

Comment: Welcome to the English stack, but commands aren't be true or false. You probably mean to ask about whether they're both grammatically correct or have different meanings. You should probably also go to the [English Language Learners stack](https://ell.stackexchange.com). They're better for basic questions like this.

Comment: Neither is true:  true does not mean correct in English.

Answer (score 1):

They are both perfectly fine. The *try not to* usage is more common in most contexts. The *try to not* usage might be more likely where one wants to put more emphasis on the idea of the repetition not happening.